# App getting stuck with E/com.facebook.internal.AttributionIdentifiers

Tags: android, facebook

App was running fine till 1 hour back. Suddenly it started getting stuck at the opening and shows 1 line error message in logcat

```
08-31 15:57:54.924 31700-31700/? E/com.facebook.internal.AttributionIdentifiers: getAttributionIdentifiers should not be called from the main thread
```

That's the only log being shown. There were no changes happened on app

Comment: same issue happend with me  , now none of solution is working

Comment: can you share your gradle file code. It'll help us to fix it faster

Answer (score 22, accepted):

this one worked for me

```
com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.35.0
```

Comment: This solved the problem for me. Took me all day to find this one line in the log... there must be a better way to get native logs from a Cordova app.

Comment: This worked for our Flutter app too, on Android it would get stuck in the slash screen. We are using Facebook plugin for sign-in.

Comment: This solved my problem, although my issue is completely different this is my issue -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71256006/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-no-virtual-method-setskipclienttokenzv-in-class-l

Answer (score 21):

If it does not help, open `android/build.gradle`.
Add next lines

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
    // ...

    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            force 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.34.0'
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

For cordova you can do:

```
$ cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-facebook4 
$ cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-facebook4 --save --variable APP_ID="123456789" --variable APP_NAME="myApplication" --variable ANDROID_SDK_VERSION="4.34.0"
```

--> https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4/blob/master/docs/android/README.md#in-case-of-conflict

Answer (score 2):

I tried each and every option. This issue was strange, showing black screen and nothing happening. Got this resolved by replacing the bundled facebook dependency
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5]' with
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.35.0'.
Finally clean, build and run.