# App frozen on white screen, react native android apk

Tags: android, react-native, android-emulator, apk, libraries

I created an app with React Native using **expo** that works on android emulator, but after generating an APK and install it on my own device, it show me a **white screen** and nothing happened. I don't know what to do, it is not crashing just stay **frozen**, so I can't take any **LogCat** info about crashing.

Here I have uploaded my code:
https://github.com/DanieleMenchetti/AwesomePlace/tree/master/AP

Can someone helping ?

**P.S.**  I used:

*React Native Image Picker*

*React Native Navigation*

*React Native Vector Icons*

*React Native Maps*

Comment: After running react-native run-android on my device it also show a white screen, but it work fine on android emulator. The emulator is the Google Pixel 2 and my own device is a Samsung S7 edge with Oreo

Comment: If you are using facebookd sdk, please check the link below https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52113549/app-getting-stuck-with-e-com-facebook-internal-attributionidentifiers

Comment: I' am not using facebook sdk, someone got my same problem??

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem using react-native version 0.55.
I downgraded to react-native version 0.49 , now it's fine.

Comment: Thanks you I will try :)

Comment: The react-native-navigation is from wix ?

Comment: Yes react native navigation I used  is from wix? Any suggestion?

Comment: It is not a question the first sentece: i took react native navigation from wix.

Comment: Okay just wanted to be sure that the navigation is from wix. Just downgrade your project and it should work after.

Comment: Oh, ok. Once I'm at home I'll try this solution, I'm so thankful to you!

Comment: How can I downgrade react native? Can you post each of the steps to get te version 0.49? Thank you so much

Comment: Also with version 0.49 I have the problem what can I do?

Comment: To downgrade I used all these commands in the root of your project: npm install react-native@x.x.x  ex: npm install react-native@0.49.4, then check your version with: react-native -v, then you should clean your android project and rebuild it with: cd android && gradlew clean, then try reseting your cache of your bundler with: react-native start --port 8083 --reset-cache, and then react-native run-android --port 8083

Comment: If your app successfully builds and is stuck at the white screen try this in chrome (your bundler must be running):  http://localhost:8083/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=false&hot=false&minify=false, to see whats the problem. If you have a problem that react can't find the index.adroid.js file create one which should be the same as index.js.
If after all these steps you are still stuck at the white screen, than the problem must be in your code somewhere

Comment: Ok thank you,now my app works on my device using Usb debugging, so then I generate an Apk following react native docs and I copy it on my phone. I install it and when I try to launch it show me only the splash screen and nothing else, what can I do? Thank you so much

Comment: Why don't you use the android studio emulator?

Comment: I use both my device and android studio emulator to open my app in debug mode, but after generating the apk and install it on my devide I had the problems I wrote before? In debug mode my app works in both emulator and device

Comment: Installing the apk on my emulator by dragging it on my emulator I got this error: Could not parse error string Apk failed to install

Comment: I don't know how to solve your other problems. If the project isn't too big, I would make a new project with clean code.