# firebase-api-initialization-failure-java-lang-reflect-invocationtargetexception

Tags: java, android

I registed app on firebase with package name `com.####.film` , it was working good.Then I have changed package name in app and in google-service.json file for testing purpose. New package name is `com.####.film.test` and it also worked good. Now I have changed package name back to original name `com.####.film`, but app does not launches and throws exception.

```
firebase-api-initialization-failure-java-lang-reflect-invocationtargetexception.
```

I have changed package name again with another name and its working fine. Even it works on all names except on my original package name `com.####.film`.
Please help me

Comment: May be you forgot to add your Package name in firebase developer console or json file.Post your complete error log.

Comment: No App is already live and with same package name, but now I am not able to run with this package name.

Comment: Here is error 
09-05 11:46:51.826 14674-14674/com.recipe.filmrise E/FirebaseApp: Firebase API initialization failure.
    java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.1:752)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zze(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.1:718)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.1:329)

Comment: Update the question your dependencies. We can trace it from there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First check if firebase is setup correctly, like dependencies are correctly added, SHA1 key is added in firebase console. If this is all set right but you are still getting the same issue. then there is definitely something wrong with other SDK dependencies you have added in build.gradle. I was facing the same issue and after lot of debugging I couldn't get this resolved. Then I tried removing firebase dependencies entirely from project, built and ran, but strangely I was still getting black screen and app getting stuck. To my luck I could find that issue was actually lying with my facebook sdk version I had added which was causing the firebase issue. I updated the facebook sdk to latest version and issue got automatically solved. You can find more here:
[App getting stuck with E/com.facebook.internal.AttributionIdentifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52113549/app-getting-stuck-with-e-com-facebook-internal-attributionidentifiers/52183274#52183274)

Comment: Thanks Mir Suhail

Comment: That has been helpful Thanks.