# Could not find class 'android.view.autofill.AutofillManager

Tags: android, react-native

My React-Native Project stopped working on these Android versions [4.2.2, 4.3, 4.4.2] weirdly enough it works on 4.4.4 and I didn't change anything in the native code or even implement any new feature, it just stopped working on newer builds even when trying to build an old working release

The log gives me two errors couldn't find any solution to them:

```
E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.autofill.AutofillManager', referenced from method com.facebook.internal.Utility.isAutofillAvailable

E/com.facebook.internal.AttributionIdentifiers: getAttributionIdentifiers should not be called from the main thread
```

Here's my build.gradle:

```
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "appname"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1199
        versionName "3.2.5"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                    versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'
    }
}


configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'org.webkit:android-jsc:r216113'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':appcenter')
    implementation project(':appcenter-crashes')
    implementation project(':react-native-blur')
    implementation project(':react-native-i18n')
    implementation project(':react-native-fbsdk')
    implementation project(':react-native-sound')
    implementation project(':react-native-audio')
    implementation project(':react-native-config')
    implementation project(':react-native-svg')
    implementation project(':react-native-picker')
    implementation project(':react-native-sentry')
    implementation project(':react-native-restart')
    implementation project(':react-native-firebase')
    implementation project(':react-native-intercom')
    implementation project(':react-native-code-push')
    implementation project(':react-native-fetch-blob')
    implementation project(':react-native-device-info')
    implementation project(':react-native-image-picker')
    implementation project(':react-native-open-notification')
    implementation project(':react-native-sensors')
    implementation project(':react-native-linear-gradient')
    implementation project(':react-native-image-crop-picker')
    implementation project(':react-native-exception-handler')
    implementation project(':react-native-flag-secure-android')
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1"
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

    implementation 'io.intercom.android:intercom-sdk-base:5.+'
    implementation 'io.intercom.android:intercom-sdk-fcm:5.+'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.2"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.1'
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.2"
    implementation 'me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.21@aar'
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}

// Apply Google services's GMS plug-in.
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Can someone please help or point me the direction I need to solve this issue

Comment: Exactly same issue here

Comment: My theory is that google pushed an update for a plugin that caused the issue and didn't inform anyone about it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution, modify your `android/build.gradle`:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
    // ...

    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            force 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.34.0'
        }
    }
}
```

original answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52148465/1216601