# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method setSkipClientToken(Z)V in class Lcom/facebook/GraphRequest;

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, build.gradle, nosuchmethoderror

It was working fine before I have done nothing, no packages update, no gradle update no nothing just created new build and this error occurs. **but for some team members the error occur after gradle sync.**

The issue is that build is generating successfully without any error but when opens the app it suddenly gets crash (in both debug and release mode)

**Error**

```
    E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3
        java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method setSkipClientToken(Z)V in class Lcom/facebook/GraphRequest; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.facebook.GraphRequest' appears in /data/app/~~aLf3pfLySq5u7zpIAr2Hlg==/com.package-name-99h4GcP3GNx2sMs76AXGvA==/base.apk)
            at com.facebook.marketing.internal.RemoteConfigManager.getRemoteConfigQueryResponse(RemoteConfigManager.java:87)
            at com.facebook.marketing.internal.RemoteConfigManager.access$000(RemoteConfigManager.java:43)
            at com.facebook.marketing.internal.RemoteConfigManager$1.run(RemoteConfigManager.java:64)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
```

---

`gradle-wrapper.properties`

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.9-all.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
```

---

`build.gradle`

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
  ext {
      buildToolsVersion = "30.0.2"
      minSdkVersion = 21
      compileSdkVersion = 30
      targetSdkVersion = 30
      ndkVersion = "21.4.7075529"
  }
  repositories {
      google()
      mavenCentral()
      jcenter()
      // maven {
      //    url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
      // }
      maven { url "https://www.jitpack.io" }
  }
  dependencies {
      classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2")
      classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'  // Google Services plugin
      // Add the Fabric Crashlytics plugin.
      // classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.31.2'
      // firebase performance sdk
      classpath 'com.google.firebase:perf-plugin:1.4.0'
      classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.7.1'


      // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
      // in the individual module build.gradle files
  }
}

allprojects {
  repositories {
      mavenCentral()
      mavenLocal()
      maven {
          // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
          url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
      }
      maven {
          // Android JSC is installed from npm
          url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
      }

      google()
      jcenter()
      maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
  }
}


subprojects {
  afterEvaluate {project ->
      if (project.hasProperty("android")) {
          android {
              buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"
              compileSdkVersion 28
          }
      }
  }
}

subprojects {
  afterEvaluate {project ->
      if (project.hasProperty("android")) {
          android {
              compileSdkVersion 29
              buildToolsVersion '29.0.3'
          }
      }
  }
}
```

---

`packages`

```json
"dependencies": {
  "@eva-design/eva": "^2.1.0",
  "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.15.14",
  "@react-native-community/blur": "^3.6.0",
  "@react-native-community/checkbox": "^0.5.0",
  "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^6.0.1",
  "@react-native-community/toolbar-android": "^0.1.0-rc.2",
  "@react-native-firebase/analytics": "^10.3.1",
  "@react-native-firebase/app": "^10.3.0",
  "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^10.3.1",
  "@react-native-firebase/crashlytics": "^10.3.1",
  "@react-native-firebase/dynamic-links": "^10.3.1",
  "@react-native-firebase/firestore": "^10.3.1",
  "@react-native-firebase/iid": "^10.3.1",
  "@react-native-firebase/in-app-messaging": "^10.3.1",
  "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^10.3.1",
  "@react-native-firebase/perf": "^10.3.1",
  "@react-native-firebase/remote-config": "^10.3.1",
  "@react-native-firebase/storage": "^10.3.1",
  "@react-native-picker/picker": "^2.1.0",
  "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.0.9",
  "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.6",
  "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.0.11",
  "@types/react-native": "^0.65.5",
  "@ui-kitten/components": "^5.1.0",
  "axios": "^0.19.0",
  "i18n-js": "^3.5.1",
  "moment": "^2.24.0",
  "native-base": "2.13.8",
  "react": "17.0.2",
  "react-content-loader": "^4.3.4",
  "react-native": "0.66.0",
  "react-native-actions-sheet": "^0.5.6",
  "react-native-adjust": "^4.28.0",
  "react-native-amplitude-analytics": "^0.2.7",
  "react-native-animatable": "^1.3.3",
  "react-native-code-push": "^7.0.4",
  "react-native-config": "^1.3.3",
  "react-native-contacts": "^5.0.7",
  "react-native-dots-pagination": "^0.2.0",
  "react-native-fbsdk-next": "^6.2.0",
  "react-native-fingerprint-scanner": "^6.0.0",
  "react-native-floating-action": "^1.22.0",
  "react-native-geocoding": "^0.4.0",
  "react-native-geolocation-service": "^5.2.0",
  "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.5.2",
  "react-native-get-random-values": "^1.4.0",
  "react-native-html-to-pdf-lite": "^0.11.0",
  "react-native-image-base64": "^0.1.4",
  "react-native-image-pan-zoom": "^2.1.11",
  "react-native-image-picker": "^4.1.2",
  "react-native-image-resizer": "^1.2.0",
  "react-native-in-app-review": "^2.1.7",
  "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.6",
  "react-native-loading-spinner-overlay": "^1.1.0",
  "react-native-material-menu": "^1.0.0",
  "react-native-material-textfield": "^0.16.1",
  "react-native-modal": "^13.0.0",
  "react-native-phone-call": "^1.0.9",
  "react-native-ratings": "^7.3.0",
  "react-native-reanimated": "^1.13.0",
  "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.3.2",
  "react-native-screens": "^3.9.0",
  "react-native-share": "^7.2.1",
  "react-native-smooth-pincode-input": "^1.0.9",
  "react-native-sms-retriever": "https://github.com/sarmad1995/react-native-sms-retriever.git",
  "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.9.1",
  "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.2.0",
  "react-native-svg": "^12.1.1",
  "react-native-version-check": "^3.4.2",
  "react-native-version-number": "^0.3.6",
  "react-native-view-shot": "^3.1.2",
  "react-native-walkthrough-tooltip": "^1.3.0",
  "react-redux": "^7.1.3",
  "redux": "^4.0.4",
  "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
  "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
  "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
  "rn-fetch-blob": "^0.12.0",
  "urbanairship-react-native": "^12.0.0",
  "uuid": "^8.3.0"
},
```

Comment: We are facing this issue only because of the Facebook dependency which is implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-marketing:4.42.0'. Once you will comment on this library then you will not see this issue. We have to post this issue on facebook github. I am also facing the same issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have fixed the issue by replacing

```
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-marketing:[4,5)'
```

by

```
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-marketing:latest.release'
```

in `android/app/build.gradle` file.

Posted this so someone out there facing the same problem will find the solution easily. It took me and my team around one and a half day to figure it out as there is no clear solution out there.

Solution Ref: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52148465/5970065)